# Streaming Websites that offer free copyright videos

Tags: piracy

I want to ask a question that they are some websites that will offer you to streams free videos that are copyrighted. For example watching a documentary like building giants( i am student of civil engineering so interested in watching it). Are we sinful for that because i am paying for the internet.

Comment: Does the internet money go to them?

Comment: Well that makes sense.

Comment: But what about things that is not available in our country? like Anime?

Comment: Your comments and orihginal posts clearly cause a confusion to me. What are you exactly asking about?

Comment: Firstly, there is no law regarding vpn and piracy in my country. Even government offices work on piracy. My question is that on the internet there are many anime sites that offer free anime like KissAnime. In their website under DCMA it's written that they take copyright seriously and will remove it if u ask them and that they are not responsible if users upload copyright content. My question is that if i stream on that website and not download or copy or Torrent them then is watching them there stealing? Because the sites that claim to be fully licensed are not even available in my country.